# "NotImplementedError at /myfile/download/8" while downloading zip file in Django

Tags: django, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to download zip file which contains multiple files in same or different formats.
This zip file get downloaded after clicking on a button "Download".

This functionality works perfectly on local development server. But after deploying the web app on Google cloud it throws

```
"NotImplementedError at /myfile/download/8"
 This backend doesn't support absolute paths.
 ...
```

Cloud storage has respective path with the file still it is not working, why?

Everything is working fine on local machine, but fails on production, why?

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry Priyashree, I was busy on other task. I will test your answer and get back to you. Thanks for the efforts.

Comment: Yes please do and let me know. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I think that calling the [path() property of the FileSystemStorage class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.Storage.path), or the [url() property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.Storage.url) where the contents of the file referenced by name can be accessed and then using absolute URLs for downloading files from either of the two is what's flagging this error:

> “For storage systems that aren’t accessible from the local filesystem,
> this will raise NotImplementedError instead.”

You should try and avoid saving to absolute paths; there is a [File Storage API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/files/storage/#module-django.core.files.storage) which abstracts these types of operations for you. Looking at the documentation, it appears that the save() function supports passing a file-like object instead of a path.
Also, if you need to serve a zip file download in Django, you just need to [serve it as attachment using Django's HttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment):

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse 
def zip_file_view(request): 
response = HttpResponse(open('/path/to/your/zipfile.zip', 'rb'), content_type='application/zip') 
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=any_name_you_like.zip' 
return response
```